Unable to use hibernate-jpamodelgen after upgrade to springboot 3
After upgrading to springboot 3:
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.6</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

I'm getting:
Fatal error compiling: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/ReflectionManager: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.ReflectionManager

My hibernate-related dependencies are:
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
  <optional>true</optional>    <!-- same behavior with or without this -->
</dependency>

which brings transitivelly:
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.6.Final</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

but it seems, that I need to declare this as a compile dependency, otherwise I'm getting this error. But if I do, I will get even more esotheric:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/jandex/IndexView: org.jboss.jandex.IndexView  

if I remove hibernate-jpamodelgen the problem disappears, but I really need this dependency, and I don't see any issue with it's declaration.
Can anyone advise?

I cannot say it's caused by xyz, but described behavior was present with:
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.6</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

but after upgrading to:
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

the issue is gone.
